# Python Pandas problem while assigning a value to a column cell using either "loc" or "at method inside loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data-frame (df) with the following columns:

```
source           company category                                             header                                            content published_date  sentiment
0  Forbes  General Electric     None  Is New England Baking The Books On Oil-Fired C...  The rise of natural gas as the primary fuel fo...     2014-01-01          0
1  Forbes  General Electric     None  DARPA Is Building A Vanishing Battery: This Po...  Considering that batteries are typically desig...     2014-01-02          0
2  Forbes  General Electric     None      Four High-Yielding ETFs For Growth And Income  Growth & income exchange-traded funds typicall...     2014-01-02          0
3  Forbes         Citigroup     None                      Analyst Moves: BAC, DUK, PZZA  This morning, Citigroup upgraded shares of Ban...     2014-01-02          0
4     WSJ          JPMorgan  MARKETS  JPMorgan Broker Barred for Role in Insider Tra...  Finra says information about merger, acquisiti...     2014-01-02          0
```

The expected result that I should get, after assigning the new valus to the column `sentiment`, is the following (over 23,000 rows in total):

```
    source           company category                                             header                                            content published_date  sentiment
0  Forbes  General Electric     None  Is New England Baking The Books On Oil-Fired C...  The rise of natural gas as the primary fuel fo...     2014-01-01          -1
1  Forbes  General Electric     None  DARPA Is Building A Vanishing Battery: This Po...  Considering that batteries are typically desig...     2014-01-02          1
2  Forbes  General Electric     None      Four High-Yielding ETFs For Growth And Income  Growth & income exchange-traded funds typicall...     2014-01-02          0
3  Forbes         Citigroup     None                      Analyst Moves: BAC, DUK, PZZA  This morning, Citigroup upgraded shares of Ban...     2014-01-02          -1
4     WSJ          JPMorgan  MARKETS  JPMorgan Broker Barred for Role in Insider Tra...  Finra says information about merger, acquisiti...     2014-01-02          1
```

The algorithm that I'm using in order to update the `sentiment` column cell values is the shown below.
Note: I verified the updated values before and after using 'at' o 'loc' inside the loop ' for e in ch_ix:'. The cell values do change, but only inside that loop.
If I try to verify by printing 'dfd['sentiment]' the resulting values are still the same 0s:

```
    dfd = db_data.copy()
    for index in range(len(stock_list_company_name)):
      cont = dfd.loc[dfd["company"] == stock_list_company_name[index]]

      #stock_data is another df which contains the columns 'ticker, date, closed, volume, sentiment' and has more rows than dfd.
      cont2 = stock_data.loc[stock_data["ticker"] == ticker_list[index]]
      dates = cont2["date"].values
      for ix in range(len(dates)):
        if(not cont.loc[cont["published_date"] == dates[ix]].empty):
          ch_ix = cont.loc[cont["published_date"] == dates[ix], "sentiment"].index
          for e in ch_ix:
           cont.at[e,"sentiment"] = cont2["sentiment"].values[ix]
    print(dfd['sentiment'] #values are still 0s
```

Can someone please help me if this is a loop lack of memory or chained indexing problem? I can't still figure out why the values are not being updated.
**Testing and running the code in this Google Colab => [url](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11D3WFzUWYioNg2XvYpKfpW9lLzI4zlQE?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop, you have this assignment:

```
cont = dfd.loc[dfd["company"] == stock_list_company_name[index]]
```

Note that this makes `cont` a new dataframe, not just a reference to a slice of the original dataframe. That's why when you change `cont`, it has no effect on `dfd`.

The easiest way to fix this is to assign the `cont` value back to the `dfd` slice, after you have made the changes to `cont`, still inside the loop:

```
dfd.loc[dfd["company"] == stock_list_company_name[index]] = cont
```

Comment: I tried it, but when I print "dfd" it still shows the same column of 0s. It works if I hardcoded the index. Could this be a for loop bug or lack of memory issue? I've got  pandas 1.3.4, and numpy 1.21.2